# Tkinter and win32api, while True crashes app

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, crash, pywin32

im working with tkinter and win32api. I've declared the next function:

```
def on_press():
        leftBtn = 0x01
        key = win32api.GetKeyState(leftBtn)
        if key < 0:
                print("Left click pressed")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                root.after(100,on_press)
        
root.after(100,on_press)
```

Already tried to do the .after to don't have two infinite loops but still crashing. Any answer??

Git to my project (not finished...): https://github.com/alexcibubins/NoRecoilScript-notFinished-.git

Comment: Remove the `while True` loop. Also you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801)

Comment: Move the `root.after(100,on_press)` one level down. Right now it only runs if the left mouse button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def on_press():
        leftBtn = 0x01
        key = win32api.GetKeyState(leftBtn)
        if key < 0:
                print("Left click pressed")
                time.sleep(0.1)
        root.after(100, on_press)
        
root.after(100,on_press)
```